# How to if/else statement in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm receiveing an error on a simple script when using if/else statement.
The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=100
if [$count > 3]; then
echo "Test IF"
fi
```

The error: /bin/ash: line 6: [100: not found

Comment: The error message is very explicit -- you're trying to run the command `[100` instead of the command `[` (which is another name for the `test` command). You can't smoosh things together -- whitespace is important.

Answer (score 12):

```
#!/bin/sh 

count=100;
if [ "$count" -gt 3 ]; then
  echo "Test IF";
fi
```

Correct your syntax: spaces must be used around `[` and `]`, parameter expansions must be quoted, and `-gt` is appropriate for numeric comparisons inside of `[ ]`. `>` in sh is used as redirection operator; if you want to use it in arithmetical comparison, you must use the bash-only syntax

```
$(( $count > 3 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ $var -eq 12 ]; then 
    echo "This is a numeric comparison if example"
fi

if [ "$var" = "12" ]; then
    echo "This is a string if comparison example"
fi

if [[ "$var" = *12* ]]; then
    echo "This is a string regular expression if comparison example"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ "$x" == "true" ]]; then

  echo "value matched"

else

 echo "value doesn't matched"

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement in shell uses the command [.
Since [ is a command (you could also use 'test'), it requires a space before writing the condition to test.
To see the list of conditions, type:
man test

You'll see in the man page that:

`s1 > s2` tests if string s1 is after string s2

`n1 gt n2` tests if integer n1 is greater than n2

In your case, using > would work, because string 100 comes after string 3, but it is more logical to write

```
if [ $count -gt 3 ]; then
   echo "test if"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also do!

```
#!/bin/sh
count=100
if [ $count -gt 3 ];
then
    echo "Test IF"
fi
```