# Unexpected end of file while trying if else condition

Tags: shell

I am just starting to learn shell and am getting this error `team.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when trying conditional if else:-

```
    #!/bin/sh
    result=2
    tmp=2
    if [ $result == $tmp ]
            echo "App is running"
    else
            echo "App is down"
    fi
```

Comment: You need to write `if [ $result == $tmp ]; then`. See: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to use conditional statements in shell. few of them are :-

Method 1:-

```
#!/bin/sh
result=2
tmp=2
if [ $result == $tmp ]
then 
        echo "App is running"
else
        echo "App is down"
fi
```

method 2:-

```
#!/bin/sh
result=2
tmp=2
if [ $result == $tmp ] ; then
                echo "App is running"
else
                echo "App is down"
fi
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641031/how-to-if-else-statement-in-shell-script) link can be useful